# Meteor Jasmine: Server Unit Stubbing Errors

Tags: meteor, jasmine, velocity

At `tests/jasmine/server/unit/z-collection-stubs.js` I have

```
Meteor.Collection.prototype._ensureIndex = function(){};
```

At `tests/jasmine/server/z-collection2.js` I have

```
Meteor.Collection.prototype.attachSchema = function () {};
Meteor.users.attachSchema = function () {};
```

The errors I'm getting

```
W20150326-10:55:08.089(-5)? (STDERR) [sanjo:jasmine]: The file "/home/jimmie/Documents/project/lib/collections/match.js" has syntax errors. [TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method '_ensureIndex']
I20150326-10:55:08.091(-5)? [sanjo:jasmine]: loading source file: /home/jimmie/Documents/project/lib/collections/user.js
W20150326-10:55:08.091(-5)? (STDERR) [sanjo:jasmine]: The file "/home/jimmie/Documents/project/lib/collections/messaging.js" has syntax errors. [TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method '_ensureIndex']
I20150326-10:55:08.093(-5)? [sanjo:jasmine]: loading source file: /home/jimmie/Documents/project/lib/routes/config.js
W20150326-10:55:08.093(-5)? (STDERR) [sanjo:jasmine]: The file "/home/jimmie/Documents/project/lib/collections/user.js" has syntax errors. [TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'attachSchema']
```

So it seem's like my stub's aren't getting set correctly though they appear to be loading before the tests are.

Comment: Most of the time when you see those syntax errors, it's because jasmine server-unit is trying to run client code or client-unit tries to run server code. Since you have those files in `/lib`, both the client and server mirrors will load it. Also, in unit mode jasmine stubs a bunch of stuff, so it's probably trying to run something in your code which it has stubbed, therefore it errors out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I had two problems.

First, the prototype I should have been stubbing to is

```
Mongo.Collection
```

and the files need to be in `test/jasmine/server/unit/` to get the load order correct.

I'm not sure what is needed to have the correct load order and stub for both client and server at the same time.